# removing rows based on two conditions from a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a country code and the corresponding country name. In some cases country is not known and `"OTHER"` is used to indicate the unknown code. My data is inconsistent, in that for some `code` I have the `country` name but also an line with `"OTHER",` for example `IRLAND` or `LUXEMBURG`.

```
code <- c(104, 105, 105, 106, 109, 112, 115, 115)
country <- c("GERMANY", "IRLAND", "OTHER", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "ITALY",  "OTHER", "LUXEMBURG")
id_country <- cbind(code, country)
id_country <- as.data.table(id_country)
```

What I want to do: I want to get unique `code` - for every code, there will be only one line, ideally with a country name, if not available then with "OTHER". I am looking for the simplest solution possible.

For now i was think of first checking if my `data.table` has some of those inconsistencies. If yes, then remove all those line that have both - country name and "OTHER" in the column `country` . I have tried the following, but none of the `duplicates` get removed

```
if (length(unique(id_country$code)) != length(unique(id_country))){

  # replace "OTHER" with the corresponding country name 
  duplicates <- id_country[duplicated(code),]
  id_country <- id_country[!(id_country$code %in% duplicates & id_country$country == "OTHER"),]

}
```

desired output:

```
code <- c(104, 105, 106, 109, 112, 115)
country <- c("GERMANY", "IRLAND", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "ITALY", "LUXEMBURG")
id_country <- cbind(code, country)
id_country <- as.data.table(id_country)
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when 2 codes (e.g. 106 and 109) have the name country, France?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option if you are willing to use `dplyr`:

> `code_n` counts the number of replicates in `code` and the `ifelse` conditionally populates the `country` variable while replacing any "OTHER" entries with `NaN` for duplicate `code`. The `NaN` entries are later filtered out. The code also works if there is a single entry for a unique code with "OTHER" as country filtering != "OTHER" will not work in that case.

```
id_country %>% group_by (code) %>% mutate(code_n=n()) %>% mutate(country = ifelse(code_n == 1,country,ifelse(country!="OTHER",country,NaN))) %>% filter(country!=NaN) %>% select(-code_n)
```

> Output

## A tibble: 6 x 2

```
# Groups:   code [6]
  code  country  
  <chr> <chr>    
1 104   GERMANY  
2 105   IRLAND   
3 106   FRANCE   
4 109   FRANCE   
5 112   ITALY    
6 115   LUXEMBURG
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions in mind. Both of them will produce the same result. The second one is maybe more appropriate if you have voluminous data because it avoids making a merge.

In your example there was no observation where only one code is associated with `OTHER`. This kind of observations won't be modified by the both methods.

## Solution 1

The first one is based on `merge`. The idea is to clean on a `data.table` that only contains the code and then merge with the initial data

```r
# METHODE 1: MERGE
id_country2 <- id_country[,.('clean_code' = unique(country)), by = code]
id_country2[, 'number_codes' := .N, by = code]
id_country2 <- id_country2[!(number_codes == 2 & clean_code == "OTHER")]

merge(id_country, id_country2)

   code number_codes   country clean_code
1:  104            1   GERMANY    GERMANY
2:  105            2    IRLAND     IRLAND
3:  105            2     OTHER     IRLAND
4:  106            1    FRANCE     FRANCE
5:  109            1    FRANCE     FRANCE
6:  112            1     ITALY      ITALY
7:  115            2     OTHER  LUXEMBURG
8:  115            2 LUXEMBURG  LUXEMBURG
```

## Solution 2

The second solution uses conditional replacement directly in the initial dataframe. The idea is to create a function before that performs the substitution and then apply it only on some codes.

The function is:

```r
replace_country <- function(x){
  val <- unique(x)
  return(
     gsub(pattern = "OTHER", replacement = val[val != "OTHER"][1],
          x)
) 
}
```

There's probably more elegant way to define it but it will do the job. By the way, I put `val[val != "OTHER"][1]` to ensure you only put one value in replacement. This might be extra carefulness but just in case.

This function will be called using `lapply`+`SD` verbs

```r
id_country[, 'number_codes' := uniqueN(country), by = "code"]
id_country[number_codes > 1,  country := lapply(.SD, replace_country), .SDcols = "country",
           by = "code"]


  code   country number_codes
1:  104   GERMANY            1
2:  105    IRLAND            2
3:  105    IRLAND            2
4:  106    FRANCE            1
5:  109    FRANCE            1
6:  112     ITALY            1
7:  115 LUXEMBURG            2
8:  115 LUXEMBURG            2
```

You only apply the `replace_country` function on the observations with `number_codes`>1 with this syntax. Your dataframe is directly updated by reference

Answer (score 0):

If the desire is to eliminate the items that have `OTHER` and all items marked `OTHER` are duplicates of another country name, we can simply select rows where country is not equal to `OTHER`.

```
library(data.table)
code <- c(104, 105, 105, 106, 109, 112, 115, 115)
country <- c("GERMANY", "IRLAND", "OTHER", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "ITALY",  "OTHER", "LUXEMBURG")
id_country <- cbind(code, country)
id_country <- as.data.table(id_country)

id_country[country != "OTHER",]
```

If there are "valid" unknown countries in the list (i.e. a non duplicated country code with a name of `OTHER`, the solution is a bit more complicated.

First, we'll find the duplicated countries after modifying the input data with a valid `OTHER`, country 117.

```
library(data.table)
code <- c(104, 105, 105, 106, 109, 112, 115, 115,117)
country <- c("GERMANY", "IRLAND", "OTHER", "FRANCE", "FRANCE", "ITALY",  "OTHER", 
             "LUXEMBURG","OTHER")
id_country <- cbind(code, country)
id_country <- as.data.table(id_country)
dupCodes <- id_country[, 'count' := .N, by = code][count > 1,.SD[1],by = code][[1]]
```

Then, we'll only delete rows where `country` is `OTHER` and there are duplicates of `code`.

```
id_country[country != "OTHER" | !(code %in% dupCodes),]
```

...and the output:

```
> id_country[country != "OTHER" | !(code %in% dupCodes),]
   code   country
1:  104   GERMANY
2:  105    IRLAND
3:  106    FRANCE
4:  109    FRANCE
5:  112     ITALY
6:  115 LUXEMBURG
7:  117     OTHER
>
```

## Correcting the original coding error

As originally written, the code in the question post includes a subtle error that causes the final subsetting operation to always fail.

```
 duplicates <- id_country[duplicated(code),]
```

Since `duplicates` is a `data.table`, not a numeric vector, the following  code fragment always evaluates to FALSE.

```
id_country$code %in% duplicates
```

The fact that this code is inside an `if()` block makes it difficult to see that `duplicates` is a data table, since we can't see it in the RStudio environment viewer. If I run the code block outside the `if()` block and inspect the object, I see the following.

[image]

Clearly `duplicates` is not a vector.

This problem causes the rest of the subsetting operation to return every row from the input data table.

```
id_country <- id_country[!(id_country$code %in% duplicates & id_country$country == "OTHER"),]
```

Why?

```
id_country$code %in% duplicates
> id_country$code %in% duplicates
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>
```

We can correct the defect by returning a vector instead of a data table from the line of code that makes the `duplicates` assignment as follows.

```
if (length(unique(id_country$code)) != length(unique(id_country))){

     # extract first column of resulting data.table as a vector
     duplicates <- id_country[duplicated(code),][[1]]
     # subset out duplicate rows named OTHER
     id_country <- id_country[!(id_country$code %in% duplicates & id_country$country == "OTHER"),]

}
id_country
```

...and the output:

```
> id_country
   code   country
1:  104   GERMANY
2:  105    IRLAND
3:  106    FRANCE
4:  109    FRANCE
5:  112     ITALY
6:  115 LUXEMBURG
>
```

Comment: so all that was needed in my code was to change `id_country[!(id_country$code %in% duplicates & id_country$country == "OTHER"),]` to `id_country[!(id_country$code %in% duplicates | id_country$country == "OTHER"),]`

Comment: ...not quite. Your code fails due to a subtle error.  As written, `duplicates` is a data frame, not a vector. Therefore, `id_country$code %in% duplicates` always evaluates to FALSE, and so the subsetting operation never deletes rows from the result.  I'll update my answer to explain how to correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

We can check condition with `if` :

```
library(data.table)

id_country[, .(country = if(any(country != 'OTHER')) 
                        country[country != 'OTHER'][1L] else 'OTHER'), code]

#   code   country
#1:  104   GERMANY
#2:  105    IRLAND
#3:  106    FRANCE
#4:  109    FRANCE
#5:  112     ITALY
#6:  115 LUXEMBURG
```